# Add Jar File to Buildpath in Windows Command Line

Tags: java, command-line, makefile, compilation

Im quite annoyed at having to ask this but I cant get it to work. Currently I have a project with:

> 5 Classes in the src/ folder
>
> 2 JARS named profiles.jar and
>   classifier.jar in the root folder

I want to create a "makefile?" or "batch file?" to compile and run these classes **FROM THE WINDOWS COMMAND LINE**, but first add the jars to the buildpath? Im not sure how I go about this

When I try to do it, it says that the class is not found, most likely due to me not adding the jars to the buildpath correctly. What are the commands I need to use to run this in command prompt?

Thanks
Philip

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help, Im having alot of trouble getting it to work tho 
Currently I have a project with 5 classes in the src folder, and 2 jars in the jar folder

Here are the commands 
Im running:

> set
>   CLASSPATH=C:\wamp\www\news\UserProfiling\jars\classifier.jar
>   ;C:\wamp\www\news\UserProfiling\jars\profiles.jar

Then from the root folder, Im running:

> javac src/*.java

Then:

> java -cp ./src:./jars/*
>   src/Interaction

Interaction is the main class, Im getting all sorts of noclassfound errors, am I doing something wrong? 
Many thanks Philip

**THE ERROR**

> java -cp ./src:./jars/* Interaction
>   Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   Interaction Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Interaction
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown
>   Source) Could not find the main class:
>   Interaction.  Program will exit.

Comment: What package is Interaction in? (i'd expect something like com.bla.Interation)

Comment: The error you are getting is from not using the full main class name, which must include the package. So instead of 'Interation' you need something like 'com.x.y.Interation'

Comment: Originally, it was in the default package, as its a very small program, but then I tried puting it in a package called test and running:

java -cp ./src:./jars/* UserProfiling.Test.Interaction

(UserProfiling is the name of my project is this right?) But I still got the same error

Comment: I noticed you keep mentioning "src", which is obviously where your Java source is. But the CP needs to point at where the compiled .class files are! Are they also in src? Also, in your previous comment you have different capitalizations of "test".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version older than or equal to Java version 5 you must specify each jar individually, and the root of your source, on your classpath e.g.

```
java -cp a.jar:b.jar:c.jar:./src MainClass
```

In version 6 you can use wildcards for the jars e.g.

```
java -cp ./src:* MainClass
```

but it might be cleaner putting your jars into a sub directory e.g.

```
java -cp ./src:./jars/* MainClass
```

So basically, your makefile or start script needs to construct a command like one of the above.

**More info** - [Sun docs (v6)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

**Update** - in response to your second edit, you need to specify the full main class name, so if the class is in a package called 'com.mypackage.MainClass' then you need to do:

```
java -cp ./src:./jars/* com.mypackage.MainClass
```

I'd also suggest getting the command working as a standalone command first, before getting the whole script running. By removing moving parts it will be faster to debug and easier to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Im having alot of trouble getting it to work tho

Currently I have a project with 5 classes in the src folder, and 2 jars in the jar folder

Here are the commands Im running:

set CLASSPATH=C:\wamp\www\news\UserProfiling\jars\classifier.jar ;C:\wamp\www\news\UserProfiling\jars

Then from the root folder, Im running:
javac src/*.java

Then:

java -cp ./src:./jars/* src/Interaction

Interaction is the main class, Im getting all sorts of noclassfound errors, am I doing something wrong?
Many thanks
Philip

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [maven](http://maven.apache.org/). Ant is a solution to do pretty much straightforward what you want to do, maven is not as straightforward but has its advantages when it comes to managing dependencies.

Comment: I'm guessing ant of maven are overkill for what Phil wants to do, which may just be a one off task. But yeah, longer term worth looking at...

Comment: ant is reasonably straightforward to set up and use, and having a project file around makes it easy to repeat the process and/or change/expand it. maven, on the other hand, is... well, I prefer to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

About your second question : if you use

```
java -cp ./src:./jars/* src/Interaction
```

it will try to launch the class src/Interaction, which does not exists. src is already in your classpath, so you just have to do

```
java -cp ./src:./jars/* Interaction
```

Comment: thanks, still getting the same error tho. Added to question description

Answer (score 0):

Found your problem, I think.

> javac src/*.java
>
> java -cp ./src:./jars/* src/Interaction

This problem plagues many beginners: You need to run javac and java from the directory where your source tree starts. In your case, that directory is `src`. Since `src` does not appear in your package names, it should also not appear in your compile/execution paths.

So you should

```
cd UserProfiling/src
```

and run

```
javac *.java
```

and

```
java -cp .:../jars Interaction
```

from there.