# JAVA rmi nested exception caused by class not found

Tags: java, rmi

I was learning rmi and I came up with a problem and I cannot solve it.
Here is the simple code

client code:

```
package rmi_test;

import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;


public class client {
public static void main(String [] args) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException
{
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1");
    DNInterface s = (DNInterface) registry.lookup("DNInterface");
    if (s.test())
        System.out.println("Hello World");
}
}
```

Interface code:

```
package rmi_test;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
public interface DNInterface  extends Remote{
      public boolean test() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Server Code:

```
package rmi_test;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
public class DataNodeImp implements DNInterface{
@Override
public boolean test() throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("test success");
        return true;
}

public DataNodeImp()
{
    super();
}
private static void boot() throws RemoteException
{
    DNInterface d = new DataNodeImp();
    DNInterface stub =
            (DNInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(d, 0);
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
    registry.rebind("DNInterface", stub);

}
public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException 
{
    String name = "DNInterface";
    boot();

}
 }
```

Then I use the following commands to compile the code

```
javac -cp src: src/rmi_test/DNInterface.java 
javac -cp src: src/rmi_test/DataNodeImp.java 
javac -cp src: src/rmi_test/client.java
```

then i type

```
rmiregistry &
```

When I try to use

```
java -cp src: rmi_test.DataNodeImp to run the server
```

it said

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 

  java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmi_test.DNInterface
```

Is there anything wrong with the command I run the code?
Why I cannot find DNInterface.class?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like you have a class path problem. The answer to this question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914493/add-jar-file-to-buildpath-in-windows-command-line

Answer (score 0):

The Registry doesn't have that class in its CLASSPATH.

The simplest solution is to use LocateRegistry.createRegistry() in the server JVM rather than rmiregistry.